# When a Quick Action creates a record can Trigger identify the Quick Action?

Tags: apex, trigger, quickaction, triggercontext

If an Quick Action creates a record and the creation of that record results in an Apex trigger being executed, can the Trigger determine which Action (if any) created the record?

The Action could, of course, set a new field (say a checkbox) to a particular value and the Trigger can then check for that value. However, the potential problem with this is if/when such a record is cloned this field will then have that particular value and the new logic will be incorrectly executed.

Comment: Check if this one helps -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm#topic-title

Comment: Thanks! So with Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity() I can determine that the trigger is being executed as a result of a Quick Action...

I guess there's no way to determine which particular Quick Action, right?

Comment: Correct. Quddity only gives you the general context.

Comment: use pre-defined fields of quick action to pass value of which action it was